# With flink sql with upset-kafka connectot, how to ignore org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

My kafka sink looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME
(
    org                                                                     VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    pod                                                                     VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    id                                                                      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    tenantId                                                                VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    eventTimestamp                                                          TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) NULL,
    contentJson                                                             VARCHAR NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (pod, org, id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
      'topic' = '${output_topic_name}',
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '${sink_kafka_servers}',
      'properties.max.request.size' = '${sink_kafka_servers}',
      'value.format' = 'json',
      'key.format' = 'json',
      'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',
      'value.json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
      'sink.buffer-flush.interval' = '${sink_flush_interval}',
      'sink.buffer-flush.max-rows' = '${sink_flush_max_rows}'
);
```

Here the contentJson can be really large sometime. I am getting this exception which is killing the job

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to send data to Kafka null with FlinkKafkaInternalProducer{transactionalId='null', inTransaction=false, closed=false} 
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaWriter$WriterCallback.throwException(KafkaWriter.java:436)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.sink.KafkaWriter$WriterCallback.lambda$onCompletion$0(KafkaWriter.java:417)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMail(MailboxProcessor.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsNonBlocking(MailboxProcessor.java:383)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:345)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:229)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:831)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:780)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:914)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1296268 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.
```

How can I get the sink to suppress this error and move to the next record. I can increase the `max.request.size` value potentially. But the contentJson can be vary by size.

Any option to ignore this error and move on ?